# Downloading a PDF file in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, download

I am facing an issue while trying to download a PDF file in a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) application.
Basically, I want to download the PDF file that is placed inside the public folder of the next js app but it is giving error "file was not available on site". Here is the code.

Code for Button:

```
"use client";

// Utility functions
import downloadPDF from "@/utils/downloadPDF";

// Components
import Button from "@/components/common/Button";

// import resume from "../../public/resume.pdf";

const ResumeButton = () => {
  const resumeClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // window.open("../../public/resume.pdf", "_blank");

    downloadPDF("../../public/resume.pdf", "HaroonAhmed.pdf");
  };
  return (
    <Button
      bgColor="bg-lime-600"
      textColor="text-white"
      className="my-4"
      handleClick={resumeClick}
    >
      Download Resume
    </Button>
  );
};

export default ResumeButton;
```

#### Utility function to download a file

```
const downloadPDF = (url, filename) => {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.download = filename;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
};

export default downloadPDF;
```

I tried to open the PDF file in a new tab using `window.open("../../public/resume.pdf", "_blank");` as well as the PDF download function, but both of these ways face the same error, "file not found". I will be happy if one of the ways works.

Comment: Hi Haroon, please "DO NOT"  share images of the code. Do share the code as a snippet or provide a codesandbox URL of feature implementation and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: ok I have updated now.

Comment: The code was provided as text, but the image link is still there and in a prominent position.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is likely due to the way you're referencing the PDF file in your Next.js application. Files in the public folder are served from the root URL, not relative to your JavaScript files or components. Therefore, you don't need to include ../../public/ in your path when trying to access these files.

Solution
To fix the problem, you should reference the PDF file using an absolute path from the root of your site, assuming that resume.pdf is directly inside the public folder. This means you should use /resume.pdf instead of ../../public/resume.pdf.

Here's how you can adjust your ResumeButton component and the downloadPDF utility function:

Adjusted ResumeButton Component:

```
const ResumeButton = () => {
  const resumeClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Use an absolute path from the root
    downloadPDF("/resume.pdf", "HaroonAhmed.pdf");
  };
  return (
    <Button
      bgColor="bg-lime-600"
      textColor="text-white"
      className="my-4"
      handleClick={resumeClick}
    >
      Download Resume
    </Button>
  );
};
```

export default ResumeButton;
downloadPDF Utility Function (No Changes Needed):

Your downloadPDF function should work fine as it is, given that the URL passed to it is correct:

```
const downloadPDF = (url, filename) => {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.download = filename;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

export default downloadPDF;
Additional Note
For the window.open approach, you should also use the corrected path:

```
window.open("/resume.pdf", "_blank");
```

This change ensures that your application correctly points to the PDF file in the public folder, allowing your users to download or view the file as intended.

Comment: It worked. thank you.
also to add info if anyone reads this in the future I figured out I didn't need the utility function to download the pdf. I can just use an "a" tag with the attribute "download" and pass the pdf path in href it will start downloading immediately when the user clicks on it.

     
        <a href="/HaroonAhmed.pdf" download>
          Download Resume
        </a>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGTP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?